# Downloading files with defined changed date time

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

Dears, could you please share your ideas how to download files from an FTP server to a local directory filtered by changed date.

So, I have a folder on the FTP server with files, but I need to move just those of them which have been changed yesterday (f.e.).

Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
open anymail.com
login
pass
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
lcd D:\Test
cd  /home/my_folder
binary
mget *
disconnect
bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardly do this with the Windows built-in `ftp.exe`.

You would have to list the remote directory, redirect the listing to a file. Then parse the listing file to find the files you want. And then generate an ad-hoc download script. Quite a lot of work.

---

Use some more capable 3rd party Windows FTP command-line client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) you can use a batch file (e.g. `download_yesterdays.bat`) like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "cd /remote/path" ^
    "lcd c:\local\path" ^
    "get *>=yesterday<today" ^
    "exit"
```

The [`>=yesterday`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#yesterday) selects files created since yesterday (inclusive). The [`<today`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#today) excludes files created today. This syntax is supported since WinSCP 5.15.

In earlier versions of WinSCP, you can use [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) instead: `>=%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyy-mm-dd%<%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%` (the `TIMESTAMP-1D` syntax is supported since WinSCP 5.9).

References:

- WinSCP guide to [Downloading the most recent file from FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file)
- [File masks with time-constraints](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time)
- [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Dear Martin,
Can I also put it on schedule?

Comment: That's for a different question. But sure you can, see WinSCP guide to [Scheduling file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

Comment: Accepted. Dear Martin, once I earn 15 points I'll rate your answer with a pleasure )).
Thank you indeed for your help. .